# How to speed up Stack 'build' with profiling enabled?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm building a program with `stack build --profile`. However, this takes a long time compared to building without profiling. It seems that it's because it has to rebuild the external libraries? Is there a way to not rebuild the external libraries or another way to speed up the builds?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to not rebuild the external libraries or another way to speed up the builds?

If you apply `--profile`, you need to build profiling versions of all the dependencies. Stack has the `--fast` flag you can use during development cycles, but it's probably not a good idea here, since the purpose of profiling is (I imagine) to get a good idea of which functions are called most often during real-world use. GHC with the optimizations off will produce very different code than GHC with the optimizations on.